# select a node with an xmlns?

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I am trying to select all of the links in a xhtml document in xsl.  Some of the anchor tags have the namespace declaration  `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` in them.  These are not selected.  e.g. with this xml doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl.xsl"?>
<root>
<item>
this iz sum text and it haz sum <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="http://cheezburger.com/">linx</a> in it.
Teh linx haz piks of <a href="http://icanhascheezburger.com/">kittehs</a> in dem.
</item>
</root>
```

and this xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<dl>
<xsl:for-each select="//root/item/a">
    <dd><xsl:value-of select="."/></dd>
    <dt><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></dt>
</xsl:for-each>
</dl>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Only the second link is selected.  Can someone explain what is going on here and how I might fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need *both* nodes, which are in different namespaces, use:

```
/root/item/*[local-name() = 'a']
```

However, this should seldomly happen, normally, you want a node from only one namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:example="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  >
....
<xsl:for-each select="/root/item/example:a">
```

Comment: this works - thanks you.  the problem here is that not all of the links are marked with the name space.

Comment: Setting the default namespace to the correct one in the stylesheet tag (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`) should work to make `/root/item/a` select all items if the other 'anonymous' nodes should be in that namespace too.

Comment: That last namespace declaration is usefull for output, not for select. XSLT 2.0 has a `xpath-default-namespace` attribute for that matter.

Comment: @Alejandro: Damn, you're right, I was not thinking straight. Good advice to the OP if all nodes should be in the same namespace is to follow your advice then :)

Answer (score 1):

The `a` elements are in 2 different namespaces, the default namespace and the xhtml namespace. If you move the XPath outside of the xhtml formatting, you can use both namespaces to search:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="links" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                  select="//root/item/(a | xhtml:a)"/>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <dl>
        <xsl:for-each select="$links">
          <dd><xsl:value-of select="."/></dd>
          <dt><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></dt>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </dl>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```